# LP - Artifical variable necessary or not for greater than sign

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method, two-phase-simplex

I am current studying LP and also the simplex method. However, the slides from my professor are not that detailed so I was trying to search for online resources. Particularly about how to convert an LP to standard form (In our definition, all equations need to be in equal signs)

However, I have been getting different answers regards what should you do when you encounter a $\geq$ sign.

One book (Larson, [Elementary Linear Algebra](https://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/4e/shared/downloads/c09s5.pdf)) explained that all you have to do is to add a surplus variable. Ex:

$$
5x_1+3x_2 \geq 10 \to 5x_1 + 3x_2-x_3 = 10
$$

However, another book (Intro to OR by Hillier) and some other resources stated that not only a slack variable is needed, but we also need to introduce an artificial variable. (And thus using either "Big-M method" or the "two-phase method" to solve it)

$$
   5x_1+3x_2 \geq 10 \to 5x_1 + 3x_2-x_3 + \overline{x}_5 = 10 \\
\text{where } \overline{x}_5 \text{ is an artificial variable}
$$

I am not really sure which way is the correct way

Comment: Add a slack to find the standard form. Add an artificial variable to solve phase 1.

Comment: You need a basic feasible solution. In your case $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_5)=(0,0,0,10)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both correct, however the first book forgot$^{(1)}$ to mention that you should add an [artificial variable](https://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/364/lessons/l3067.pdf) as if we took the following:

$$
5x_1+3x_2 \geq 10 \to 5x_1 + 3x_2-x_3 = 10
$$

and put it into a tableau we would get:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & RHS\\
\hline ? & 5 & 3 & -1 & 10 \\ \hline
\end{array}

since we have no starting basic variable for the Simplex Method, we'd be forced to make one like so:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & RHS\\
\hline x_1 & 1 & \frac{3}{5} & -\frac{1}{5} & 2 \\ \hline
\end{array}

$$\text{or}$$

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & RHS\\
\hline x_2 & \frac{5}{3} & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{10}{3} \\ \hline
\end{array}

$$\text{or}$$

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & RHS\\
\hline x_3 & -5 & -3 & 1 & -10 \\ \hline
\end{array}

The third tableau is invalid if $x_3$ has the non-negativity constraint $x_3\ge0$. The above only really works if we have only one constraint in the model, or if $x_1$ or $x_2$ only appears in this constraint and no other.

Suppose we have the following constraints of a model:
$$5x_1+3x_2 \ge 10$$
$$x_1+x_2 \le 5$$

Since we cannot simply add just a negative slack to the first constraint as we'll have no starting basic variable in that row, and we can't just modify $x_1,x_2$, or $x_3$ to be a starting basic variable, we'll have to add an artificial variable like so:

$$5x_1+3x_2 -x_3+a_1= 10$$
$$x_1+x_2 +x_4 = 5$$

Where $a_1$ is the artificial variable. Which will look like the following in the initial tableau:
\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & a_1 & RHS\\
\hline a_1 & 5 & 3 & -1 & 0 & 1& 10 \\
\hline x_4 & 1 & 1 &  0 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{array}

However, the introduction of an artificial variable does impact our objective function in a significant way. Thus, you should look into the [Big-M](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ecs2035/courses/ieor3608.F05/david-bigM.pdf) and the [Two-Phase](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi//henry/teaching/f05/350.f05/L18.pdf) methods for more information on how to add artificial variables into the objective function.

---

$(1)$ Forgot is a loaded term, they might have meant for the reader to be creative on trying to derive a basic variable without trying to use the artificial variable technique like what was shown, as it is often better for a model to not ever have to deal with artificial variables.